# Any example related to function testing and edge cases in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, jestjs, azure-functions

Can anyone share any example related to edge case testing in javascript and also any example related to function testing in javascript using jest.

```
const activityFunction: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context): Promise<string> {
    try {
        let mappingArr = [] as any;
        mapCategoryNameToNameOfNetwork(mappingArr, context);
        return
    } catch (err) {
        context.log.error("Error while mapping category name to name of networks", err)
        throw err;
    }
};



I want to test this function as this is giving blank response. I am not able to test it like i was testing for normal functions. Do anyone have any solution that how i should move ahead with this?
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask), [*What types of questions should I avoid asking?*](/help/dont-ask), and [*What topics can I ask about here?*](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Create an Azure JavaScript Function in VS Code and test it locally.

[image]

Here, a folder for HTTP Trigger1 is created.

2. Create another folder named as testing under the root of the project in VS Code and run these commands in the terminal of same order:

```
npm init -y
npm i jest
```

It adds the required packages to the project for testing the function with jest.

3. Update the *`package.json`* to replace the existing test command:

```
    "scripts": {
        "test": "jest"
    }
```

It looks like:
[image]

4. In a testing folder, create a file by naming it as defaultContext.js and add this code:

```
    module.exports = {
        log: jest.fn()
    };
```

It mocks the log function in default context.

5. In the Azure Function Folder (i.e., HTTP Trigger1 Folder), add a new file index.test.js by adding this test code:

```
    const httpFunction = require('./index');
    const context = require('../testing/defaultContext')
    
    test('Http trigger should return known text', async () => {
    
        const request = {
            query: { name: 'Bill' }
        };
    
        await httpFunction(context, request);
    
        expect(context.log.mock.calls.length).toBe(1);
        expect(context.res.body).toEqual('Hello Bill');
    });
```

These are steps and code format of running the JavaScript Azure Function using Jest.

6. To Run the test, use this code in the VS Code Terminal: `npm test`

If the test failed, it shows like below:

[image]

And Here the test is failed because in the test script, the result string should be like `Hello {name}` where as in the boilerplate code of Azure Function Http Trigger, the result string is `Hello, {name}. This function executed successfully.`

So both doesn't match, the test failed.
Modified the HTTP Trigger Function to output the result string same as test script result i.e., `Hello {name}`

[image]

The test is passed as the function's output is `Hello Bill` which is same as the Test Script expected output.

Here are the references for the Azure JavaScript Function Testing using Jest and the edge cases testing:

1. [Microsoft Documentation of Azure JavaScript Functions Testing & Debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#javascript-in-vs-code).
2. [Edge Cases Testing Code in the Functions](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dont-forget-edge-cases/)
3. [Testing JavaScript with Jest](https://vegibit.com/testing-javascript-with-jest/)

Comment: You answered half of my question. But in the response i am getting blank response. So i want to know that how can i test a function which returning blank response.

Comment: @AnshulSharma, Please check every step you followed because if the response format doesn't match from test code to main code, then no response is recorded as I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @AnshulSharma, Any Update to the issue?

Comment: As you mentioned that if the response format doesn't match from test code to main code, then no response is recorded as I mentioned in the answer then how we can test in that case.

Comment: @AnshulSharma, I have shown you the failure case for unmatching format and the success output also in the answer. Please check the answer!

Comment: But that test case failed which is not acceptable

Comment: @AnshulSharma, please check the given references, where I followed the same and got the result.

Comment: @AnshulSharma, please check this reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-test-a-function#javascript-in-vs-code given in the answer